# Firebase + Flutter + Web Having No Data

Tags: firebase, flutter, web, dart, firebase-authentication

## 1. The Problem

I'm trying to integrate my Flutter app — it works fine, with tests and mocks, on Android and iOS so far — to the web, but, despite following the HTML configurations and other tutorials and my simple authentication app working fine overall, I get that no data is reaching it. My snapshots have `snapshot.hasData == false` and its `connectionState` is `ConnectionState.waiting`.

## 2. The Code

I'm not having any errors aside from this weird, no-data behavior. My `index.html` file is configured this way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="feedbacker">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>feedbacker</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
        application. For more information, see:
        https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <!-- Firebase -->

  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = { ... }; // copy-paste from Firebase's configuration setup
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>

  <script src="main.dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## 3. Additional Info

I've tried many variations of `firebasejs`' versions and none of them worked, specially not the most recent ones.

The version of the revelant packages I'm using are:

```yaml
firebase_auth: ^0.15.2
google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
```

`google_sign_in` and `flutter_facebook_login` are optional workflows and they also aren't working.

> I won't be able to share the whole app here because there's too much stuff there. Given the amount of problems I'm having now, I should have started to port it to the web at the beginning, though I didn't know Flutter supported it at the time.

Comment: You said you have tried various versions of firebasejs - and they didn't work - did they gave an error? Also, why are you preferring version 7.5 over 7.15?

Comment: I did try 7.15 as well. The example above is from with the lowest version I tried, no specific reason for it. I don't get any error messages on the terminal when running the app through `flutter run -d chrome` (the `web-server` option also doesn't work), which makes things way more annoying to debug.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I tried it again about a month after posting it and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have gotten this working.

```dart
void main() async {
  // Ensure setup is finished before running app.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Globals {
  static FirebaseAuth auth;
  static User user;
}

class Routes {
  static final String signinScreen = 'signinScreen';
  static final String appScreen = 'appScreen';
  static final String loadingScreen = 'loadingScreen';
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      routes: {
        Routes.signinScreen: (context) => SigninScreen(),
        Routes.appScreen: (context) => AppScreen(),
        Routes.loadingScreen: (context) => LoadingScreen(),
      },
      initialRoute: Routes.loadingScreen,
    );
  }
}
```

LoadingScreen:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // Initialize Firebase Authentication.
  // I use a global variable so I can access it everywhere.
  Globals.auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<User>(
    // Listen to the auth stream from Firebase.
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
      // Wait for the stream to be active.
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        // Check if there is a user.
        // If yes, start the app; if no, start the sign in screen.
        // On web this always comes up null, so we get to the sign in screen.
        if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
          return AppScreen();
        } else {
          return SigninScreen();
        }
      }
      return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  );
}
```

SigninScreen:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _checkIfSignedIn());
}

// Workaround because the initial StreamBuilder
// always returns null on the web version.
// May have something to do with this bug that was just fixed,
// but will need verification:
// https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/4312
void _checkIfSignedIn() async {
  // Slight delay for any potential user info to actually populate.
  // We can't do this directly in the StreamBuilder since it
  // doesn't work with async.
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  // **Now** check if there is a logged in user.
  if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
    print('User is logged in, moving to main app screen.');
    // Replace `Routes.appScreen` with your desired app screen.
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.appScreen);
  } else {
    // No saved user loaded, so continue normal sign in.
    print('User not logged in.');
  }
}
```

I have been fighting with this for days, partly because no examples or answers were complete; so I tried to be as complete as possible for anyone else that may have this issue.